# Can I print output to stderr in batch mode WITHOUT a trailing newline?

Tags: files, batch-mode, print

In emacs --batch  (also, emacs --script),

```
(message "My Message")
```

will print "My Message" to standard error (file descriptor 2) along with a trailing newline.

What if I don't want the newline?  I see that theoretically,

```
(princ "My Message" standard-error)`
```

would work, if `standard-error` were defined.

Confusingly, `standard-output` and `standard-input` *are* defined, however.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I found that `(defvar standard-error 'external-debugging-output)` makes the above behave nicely, thanks to @wasamasa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the manual, anything printing a message in batch mode will use stderr for this.  The `print`/`prin1`/`princ` family will continue printing to stdout unless you pass the optional argument for picking a different char printing function, therefore the following will work:

```
(princ "My Message" 'external-debugging-output)
```

Apparently the Emacs developers consider stderr only for reporting errors and debug output ;)

Comment: How did you find that out?

Comment: I jumped to the sources of `princ` with `find-function`, then searched the sources for usage of `stderr`.  Eventually I found that special char printing function...